# Error : virtual memory exhausted: Cannot allocate memory while installing SciPy

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, scipy

I am trying to install SciPy in my Amazon AWS which has 1GB RAM and I ended up with error saying "virtual memory exhausted: Cannot allocate memory". As per [this link](http://naokiwatanabe.blogspot.in/2014/12/install-numpy-schipy-matplotlib-and-etc.html) I did

```
sudo /bin/dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/swap.1 bs=1M count=1024
sudo /sbin/mkswap /var/swap.1
sudo /sbin/swapon /var/swap.1
```

but it didn't work for me. Also I did lot of Googling and none of the solutions worked for me. The way I am trying to install is using pip from the following command `python -m pip install scipy`.How can I overcome this error and install SciPy?

Comment: Well, have you tried allocating more than 1GB of swap space? Compiling scipy is quite resource-intensive - a simpler option would be to install it from a binary using the system package manager (e.g. `sudo apt-get install python-scipy` for Ubuntu).

Comment: Have you thought about installing a binary? Either rpm or anaconda?